# Nginx Re-write: Different URL based on incoming URL format

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a server that will have 2 different types/formats of requests coming in. Both request URL's will start with: `http://myredirect.mycompany.com/browse/`. After '/browse/' it will either be a number:

`http://myredirect.mycompany.com/browse/12345, it can be any number`

or it will be 2 to 4 capital letters followed by a '-' followed by a number:

`http://myredirect.mycompany.com/browse/QA-12345`

What I want to do redirect to a different URL that's based on the incoming URL. For example:

```
http://myredirect.mycompany.com/browse/12345 would redirect to http://serverA.mycompany.com/show_item.cgi?12345
```

and

```
http://myredirect.mycompany.com/browse/QA-12345 would redirect to http://serverB.mycompany.com/browse/QA-12345
```

I think what I want is to use an nginx rewrite but I'm not sure how to form. From what I've googled, you can use regex in rewrites so I could use something like

```
^(/browse/[0-9])?
```

for the first one. But how do I actually pull that number into the redirect URL? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading [nginx's documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) and the [PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org/) documentation can help you understand how rewrite and regex work.

For your example you would need a location block wrapping two rewrite rules like this :

```
location /browse {
    rewrite ^/browse/(\d+)$ http://serverA.mycompany.com/show_item.cgi?$1 [flag];
    rewrite ^/browse/([A-Z]{2,4}-\d+)$ http://serverB.mycompany.com/browse/$1 [flag];
}
```

Replace `[flag]` with `permanent` or `redirect` depending on desired redirect code (301 or 302).

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.